# Dealing with a coincidental need to jump every year?

Tags: job-search

I am a software engineer with two years experience since graduation. In that time I have had two jobs. I left the first one as all the senior developers got poached in the first developer boom. At one year of experience, I was the 2nd most senior person on the frontend team before I left.

I left to a team which has 3 seniors, most with 10+ years of experience and with that experience with well known companies. I learned a ton from them. I am now at a company where it has happened again. I am the most experienced person on the team as all the senior developers left and then all the intermediate developers left and in the past 4 months my company has not been able to replace them. I just learned yesterday that they have given up on replacing them unless one walks in.

Other than what I have been learning on Udemy, I have not learned a lot and projects have been dramatically scaled down as the skills do not exist to do complicated work.

I want to jump again and can get interviews, including with Amazon, Square, and Stripe so I think my resume is ok, but I am scared to accept them as each job would be at exactly or within one month of a year and that looks like I am just hanging around the bare minimum and quitting.

Help pls?

Comment: Well if you get a job at one of those places you mentioned (or similar) it's unlikely you'll lose all your senior teammates again. Then you can stay longer and the short stints won't matter so much.

Comment: @jcm well yes, I think I am done with the startup world after this but I want to be well prepared if asked about it. I know you shouldn't criticize your old employer in an interview and saying that I didn't learn as much for the last few months also sounds bad but I do not know what to say.

Comment: You can put some explanation in your cover letter.  "Having had some unexpected turnover  in my previous employment, I am keen to join a stable yet exciting company where I can continue to learn, improve my skills to show my potential and stay for the long haul benefiting both me and <company>".  Be prepared to talk to this in the interview.

Comment: It's not wrong to leave a failing company. A company that loses all its senior staff and is "unable to replace them" is a failing company. Did any managers leave?

Comment: @Nelson no, but they aren't generally technical. They also get options, which non leaders do not get.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Slight* frame challenge: this wasn't 100% coincidental. You joined two small companies, and small companies have the risk of being a bit more unstable in terms of staff stability as they're typically dependent on just one or two members of staff in each area - and if those staff leave for any reason, they don't have ready-made replacements on other teams that they can use to backfill. If you were now applying for roles at a third small company, I'd be a little bit worried that you would leave again if there were any staff turnover.

On the other hand, you can flip this around to explain why you're now applying to larger companies:

> I've realised I'm someone who values a bit of stability in my working environment, so (insert company name here) really appealed to me.

Comment: So you want to hire someone who when other people are leaving, they stay. Is that realistic? The key phrase here is "has not been able to replace them". If someone isn't willing to wait the 1-3 months it takes to replace someone then maybe thats a problem. But working with smart people on an interesting mission is part of what a startup can offer (otherwise the equity better be amazing). Senior engineers not wanting to join a place is a big red flag. I'd probably get out too

Comment: The point here isn't _actually_ what you really think about it all, it's about how to present it in the best light when applying for your next role.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the advice on how to best present your job history, and also to apply for jobs at larger, hopefully more stable companies.

I'm sure that some places will look at your job history, label you a 'job-hopper', and not interview you.  You will never know about that.  The ones who interview you will either be desperate or willing to see how you explain yourself.

Watch for red flags, and try out various ways of explaining your job history with mock interviews.

Answer (score -1):

If you make sure you stay at your next role for a decent amount of time then I doubt future employers will care about short stints in the past.
The reason short stints are seen negatively is that it can indicate poor performance and being managed out or it can indicate someone that doesn't know what they want in a career. 1-2 can be easily explained by problems like the one you faced but the more this happens the harder it is to put it down to be the employers fault.
So understanding this, a 2-3 year stints at a place like Amazon should completely dispel this concern. It shows you are able / willing to stay longer at a place. In addition, it being the most recent employer will inherently make it count more.
So in short don't worry about moving. Just make sure it is to a place that you are happy to stay. Those are all big companies so I imagine teams will differ!